# jax: instead of ser: - JavaWS

Tags: java, java-ws

Request from my Web Service looked like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://mywebservice.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:something>
```

Now, it looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:jax="http://mywebservice.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <jax:something>
```

What´s the difference between jax and ser? I get the same answers and apparently nothing has changed.

Comment: That's just the XML namespace definition. You can name your namespace however you want as long as it is unique in the whole document.